# Json response in Codeigniter

Tags: json, codeigniter

Below is the code for user list webservice's json response.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Webservice extends CI_Controller 
{
        function  list_user()
        {   
                $result_login = $this->db->get('user_registration')->result();
                $response = array();
                $response ["success"] = 1;          
                $response ["message"] = "User List.";
                foreach($result_login as $row)
                {
                        $data = array();
                        $data['User Id'] = $row->user_id;
                        $data['Name'] = $row->name;
                        $data['Email'] = $row->email;
                        $data['mobile_number'] = $row->mobile_number;
                        $data['Password'] = $row->password;
                        $output2 = json_encode(array('responsedata' => $data));
                         echo $output2;
                }

        }
}
?>
```

In my code if i replace $data with $response in json_encode then i can't get $data's value. 
I got json response in this format. JSON Response.

```
    {
        "responsedata": {
                  "User Id": "7",
                  "Name": "bhavin",
                  "Email": "bhavin123@gmail.com",
                  "mobile_number": "123456789",
                  "Password": "abc"
  }
}
```

But i want json response in this format.

```
{
       "responsedata":
        {
        "success": 1,
        "data": [
          {
                      "User Id": "7",
                      "Name": "test",
                      "Email": "test1@gmail.com",
                      "mobile_number": "123456789",
                      "Password": "abc"
          },
          {
                      "User Id": "8",
                      "Name": "test2",
                      "Email": "test2@gmail.com",
                      "mobile_number": "123456789",
                      "Password": "abc"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to arrange Your array like this

I update below code

```
$array_of_event = array()
foreach($result_login->result_array() as $row)
{
$array_of_event[] = $row;
}
    $data['success'] = "1";
    $data['data'] = $array_of_event; //need to assign event here
    $response['responsedata'] = $data;

    echo json_encode($response);
```